# How to one file copy to all subfolders

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim fi As New FileInfo("C:\Users\x\Desktop\test\1.save") 'source file
        Dim dirs As DirectoryInfo() = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\x\Desktop\Backup").GetDirectories() 'target folder

        For Each d As DirectoryInfo In dirs
            fi.CopyTo(d.FullName, True)
        Next
```

I have a single file so i want to copy file another folder and **only the deepest subfolder** like this C:\Users\x\Desktop\Backup\randfolder\rand23

just tried something like that but not worked

I'd appreciate it if you could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using [`File.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_) and some loops to get the deepest folders:

```
Dim strSourceFilePath As String = "C:\Users\x\Desktop\test\1.save"
Dim folders As String() = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Users\x\Desktop\Backup", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim maxDepth As Integer = 0

'get the max depth
For Each dirName As String In folders
    Dim currentDepth As Integer = dirName.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Length
    If maxDepth < currentDepth Then
        maxDepth = currentDepth
    End If
Next

'second loop to copy to deepest folders.
For Each dirName As String In folders
    Dim currentDepth As Integer = dirName.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Length

    'just copy to the deepest folders.
    If currentDepth = maxDepth Then
        File.Copy(strSourceFilePath, Path.Combine(dirName, Path.GetFileName(strSourceFilePath)), True)
    End If
Next
```

You have to create the target file path using the directory path and the filename of the source file (or any other filename you want). Using [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_) you can put the directory path and the filename together to get the target file path.

Comment: Thank you but ur code just copy one subfolder but i need copy file last subfolder
i mean C:\Users\x\Desktop\Backup this main folder but i want copy C:\Users\abdullahPc\Desktop\TC\random434\1283 this folder thats possible ?

Comment: can you describe / show the folder structure in your question? what is the root folder containing the sub folders? you want to copy the file recursive to all available sub folders?

Comment: You have to define *last subfolder*

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Yes, definitely example; http://prntscr.com/r1p1gt

Comment: @Boran So do you mean the deepest subfolder, and only the deepest subfolder? So, if it was `C:\A\B\C`, you want to copy the file to *only* `C:\A\B\C` but not `C:\A\B`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, exactly copy the file to only C:\A\B\C not C:\A\B

Comment: @Boran OK, so what if there are folders `C:\A\B\C` and `C:\A\B\D`? Do you want it copied to both or only `C:\A\B\D`?